# MongoDB - Xubuntu crouton - can't start service

Tags: linux, mongodb, unix, crouton-os

I've tried following the installation instructions laid out here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

But I run into a problem with, I'm guessing, Upstart/initctl and I can't get the mongod service to start other than by running it manually as sudo in a terminal, which is a Bad Idea IMO. (Even if this is merely for a classroom, single-user setup.)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start
```

Yields this error:

```
initctl: Unknown job: mongod
```

I've tried `sudo initctl reload-configuration` and running the above start command again, to no avail.

Any ideas or suggestions on what to do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing mongodb using what the official documentation doesn't seem to work in crouton. Below are the instructions I followed to get it working on my machine (crouton running elementaryOS)

1. Download the physical mongodb package for linux (can be obtained from mongodb.org)
2. Extract the mongodb package using `tar -xvzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7.tgz`
3. Make the installation directory (`sudo mkdir /usr/lib/mongodb`)
4. Copy the extracted mongodb into to /usr/lib/mongodb (`sudo mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7 /usr/lib/mongodb`)
5. Make the data directory (`sudo mkdir -p /data/db`)
6. Start mongodb (`sudo /usr/lib/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x84_64-2.6.7/bin/mongod &`)